# Unable to find values stored in Collection, if exist or not,If not exist save in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

code for saving Splunk User data into MongoDb using Node API. I am able to store data in MongoDb but I am facing issue in checking the presence of User data in Db. i.e., i need to check if the user already exists or not, if Yes it should say "User Exists" else it should get added in Database. This is where I got suck and I need help to solve this issue.

```
.post(function (req, res) {
    var db = new mongoOp();
    var response = {};
    db.find({
        'email': req.body.email
    }).exec(function (err, data) {
        response = {
            "error": false,
            "message": data
        };
        if (data) {
            alert("user exist");
        } else {
            db.email = req.body.email;
            db.IP = req.body.IP;
            db._time = req.body._time;
            db.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    response = {
                        "error": true,
                        "message": "Error fetching data"
                    };
                } else {
                    response = {
                        "error": false,
                        "message": data
                    };
                }
                res.JSON(response);
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: Error display in Npm while click post button from client side, ReferenceError: db is not defined
    at /Users/Gugan/Work/NodeAPI/NodeAPI/server.js:58:2

Comment: Please add these errors also in question

Comment: Will you please share /server.js ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xoeu7hhr2uk1ure/server.js?dl=0

Comment: there is alert in serverjs , please remove and use console ,
Also add console.log(data) on line 45 just to make sure data is coming from find operation

Comment: Issue from Browser "POST http://localhost:3000/users 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Also, `db.find` would return an empty array. 
`if(emptyArray)` is actually true so if will give you fake true